# How to disable IE11 WebBrowser for image resizing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, fckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Hi iam using CKeditor for text editor in my code and i have disabled the width and height property in image properties to block resizing the image. When i select the image am able to drag and resize to block that i have used "config.disableObjectResizing = true;" it works fine in < IE11. In IE11 it doesn't work. Please help me to overcome this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Unfortunately it's not possible in IE11.

Work Around is:

```
var editable = editor.editable(),
    element = editable.$;

if ( element.addEventListener ) {
    // IE up to 10.
    element.addEventListener( 'mscontrolselect', function( evt ) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    } );
} else {
    // IE11 and higher.
    element.attachEvent( 'oncontrolselect', function( evt ) {
        evt.returnValue = false;
    } );
}
```

Please refer below link for more details:

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9317#comment:16

Comment: Can you guide me where to apply this patch ?

Comment: @Deepak, please add a working jsfiddle for usage example.